# Replace displayed array commas with line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this piece of code that fetches some links in `<li>` elements and then put their content into an array. Which works fine.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="links">
    <li><a href="#" title="Open this form">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Open this form">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Open this form">Test 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="temporary-pool"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var links = [];

$("#links li").each(function() {
    var rawLinks = $(this).html()
    var textLinks = rawLinks.replace(/<a\b[^>]*>/i,"").replace(/<\/a>/i, "");

    links.push(textLinks);
});

console.log(links);     

$("#temporary-pool").html(
    '<textarea  id="clean-links">'
        +links+
    '</textarea>'
);
```

However, I would like to display the content in a `<textarea>`. When I simply print it, it obviously outputs as:

```
Test 1,Test 2,Test 3
```

What I would like, is for it to output the result as:

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

I tried playing around with regex (I believe I need to replace "," with "
") but not successfully.

Comment: You print a list, It should work: `links.join("\n")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("#temporary-pool").html(
    '<textarea  id="clean-links">'
        +links.join("\n")+
    '</textarea>'
);
```

You can find more info about `join(...)` [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

And to simplify the other part of your code, you can do something like this:

```
$("#links li").each(function() {
   links.push($(this).text());
});
```

Info about `jQuery.text()` [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Awesome, clean and nice. You're a life saver. Thanks for the answer and advice, duly noted.

Comment: @morgi I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use a line break, and substring out the comma like

var links = [];

```
$("#links li").each(function() {
    var rawLinks = $(this).html()
    var textLinks = rawLinks.replace(/<a\b[^>]*>/i,"").replace(/<\/a>/i, "");

    links.push(textLinks.substring(0, textLinks.length-1) + "\n");
});

console.log(links);     

$("#temporary-pool").html(
    '<textarea  id="clean-links">'
        +links+
    '</textarea>'
);
```

assuming the comma is the last character of the original strings are a comma, otherwise the commas are coming from outputting an array directly.
In which case, make it a string:

```
var txtValue = "";
for(var i = 0;i<links.length;i++){
    txtValue = txtValue + links[i];
}

$("#temporary-pool").html(
    '<textarea  id="clean-links">'
        +txtValue+
    '</textarea>'
);
```

Comment: I tried that already, it outputs the line breaks but does not remove the commas.